# How do I force Scrollview to start from the top of the child view?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, childviews

I have a simple ScrollView set up in a landscape layout.  When I rotate the device from portrait to landscape mode, the UI screen scrolls down a bit and the topmost portion of the view is no longer visilble.  How do I force the view to start at the top of the view?  I tried setting "mScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);" programmatically but with no luck.  Please advise.

partial land\layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".CardViewActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" >
</include>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:useDefaultMargins="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingEnd="2dp"  >
```

partial Activity file:

```
...
private ScrollView mScrollView;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView1);
    if (mScrollView!=null) {
        mScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(false);
        mScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
        mScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the background, I would advice to use the same layout, with scrollview, for portrait as well. Scrollview would do the job automatically.

Comment: I am only using the Scrollview in a land\layout file. The portrait layout file does not use a Scrollview. So when I set up mScrollView in the Activity it crashes--I think becuase it is trying to set the mScrollView on the portrait layout and their is no ScrollView to be set in that portrait layout.  Would I have to set up the fullScroll code in onResume but use some type of "if" statement to only use the  code only if the device is in landscape orientation?

Comment: you should simply check before you use your `mScrollView` like this `if (mScrollView!=null) { //do your stuff with mScrollView }`

Comment: My apologies.  I have just accepted the answer.  How does the "!null" negate the mScrollView being used in portrait mode if mScrollView is set in the Activity?

Comment: `mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView1);` when you get the `mScrollView`, if it fails to find, the function will returns **null**, which is a special state for Object in Java, meaning it is nothing. `!=` means NOT equal, so the whole statement `mScrollView != null` means it is not **nothing**, in portrait mode, because you have not define the view in your layout, mScrollView will be set to `null`, but as you check everytime, you will not try to work on it which would result in error.

Comment: Ok, I put the fullScroll code in the onResume method.  I edited my question above to show the onResume section.  I tested and it does not work.  I also tried "scrollTo(0,0)" and that did not work either.  Thoughts?

Comment: your scrollview should not define height as wrap content

Comment: scrollview cannot depends on child for height

Comment: Ok, I changed height to match_parent.  I also edited my question to show the top portion of the land\layout file in case that helps.  I tested with match_parent and it still does not work.  Thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89499/discussion-between-derek-fung-and-ajw).